# code in mips with use of "push" without "pop"

Tags: c, assembly, mips

code in c:

```
int recursive_power (int base, int power) 
{
    if (power <=0)
        return (-1);
    else    if (power ==1)
        return (base);
    else
        return (base*recursive_power (base, power-1)); }
```

mips:

```
recursive_power:    addi $sp, $sp, -8   #Assign stack space
        sw $ra, 0($sp)  #Store current value of $ra
        sw $a1, 4($sp)  #Store current value of power
        slti $t0, $a1, 1    #if power<1, $t0==1, else $t0==0;
        beq $t0, $0, next   #power>0, continue ($t0==0)

        addi $v0, $0, -1    #power<=0, return -1
        j return2

    next:   addi $t1, $0, 1 #put ‘1’ in $t1
        beq $a1, $t1, return1   #if power==1, return(base)

        addi $a1, $a1, -1   #power=power-1
        jal recursive_power #call recursive_power (base,power-1)

        lw $ra, 0($sp)  #Restore original return address
        lw $a1, 4($sp)  #Restore original value of power
        mul $v0, $a0, $v0   #return value is $v0*base
        j return2

    return1:    addi $v0,$a0, 0 #$v0=base
    return2:    addi $sp, $sp, 8    #Restore stack
        jr $ra      #Return to caller address
```

Is it correct to make "return1" "return2" as they appear in this code, since there will be no "lw" commend? Doesn't any use of stack-"push" requires also "pop"? May you help with improving the mips code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed your pops in the wrong place. You're pushing two registers onto the stack every time you enter the function, so you should pop them every time you return from the function:

```
    jal recursive_power #call recursive_power (base,power-1)
    mul $v0, $a0, $v0   #return value is $v0*base
    j return2

return1:    addi $v0,$a0, 0 #$v0=base
return2:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)  #Restore original return address
    lw $a1, 4($sp)  #Restore original value of power
    addi $sp, $sp, 8    #Restore stack
    jr $ra      #Return to caller address
```